# Verifying if there are three elements that are the same and two elements that are the same in a list

Tags: haskell, recursion, permutation

I am given a list of 5 elements drawn from the list `[1..6]` sorted in ascending order, and I have to develop two functions:

- check if there are *exactly* 4 equal elements (e.g. `11112`, `44445`, `15555`),
- check if there are *exactly* 3 equal elements, and *exactly* 2 equal elements (e.g. `22244`,`11122`)

I can assume functions like `numberOfOccurrences`, `isPermutation`, `isSorted`, `maximum`, and `minimum`.

```hs
numberOfOccurrences :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
numberOfOccurrences _ [] = 0
numberOfOccurrences x (y:ys)
  | x == y    = 1 + numberOfOccurrences x ys
  | otherwise = numberOfOccurrences x ys

isPermutation :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isPermutation [] [] = True
isPermutation xs [] = False
isPermutation xs (y:ys) | length xs /= length (y:ys) = False
                        | otherwise = isPermutation (delete y xs) ys
```

My solution for the second one is:

```
p :: [Int] -> Bool
p xs = 3 == maximum (map length (group xs))
```

However, I should use the function `isPermutation`, and `numberOfOccurrences`. Any hints about this problem ?

Thanks to Daniel Wagner for finding my error. This would be the solution to 2, I think.

```hs
p :: [Int] -> Bool
p xs = 3 == maximum ns && length ns == 2
    where 
        ns = (map length (group xs))
```

However, it is not the solution required.

Comment: If there are four equal elements, this implies that there are three equal elements.

Comment: Thank you, Willem ! I should clarify that. Exactly 4 elements.

Comment: why should you use `isPermutation`?

Comment: I don't think your solution for the second one is right. For example, try `[1,2,3,3,3]`.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @Code-Apprentice. I should use `isPermutation` because it is required in the exercise.

Comment: Thank you, @Daniel Wagner. I'll fix it.

Comment: I don't see how `isPermutation` will help you solve the exercise to determine if there are exactly 4 identical elements in a list. These are two very different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd start with the super dumb thing.

```
fourEqual [a, b, c, d, e] =
       (a == b && b == c && c == d && d /= e)
    || (a /= b && b == c && c == d && d == e)
```

It's easy to write, it's easy to read, and it isn't particularly inefficient.

A similar strategy works for the other one.

Comment: Thank you very much. +1 Always appreciate your answers. Do you know if it's possible to use `isPermutation` to define it ? It is required in my exercise.

Comment: @F.Zer I can't think of any meaningful way to use `isPermutation` for this. If meaningless is good enough, there are a variety of ways, with the simplest (but also most obviously meaningless) being `fourEqual [...] = const (... || ...) isPermutation`. But rather than doing that, it is probably best to chat with your instructor about *why* this requirement exists.

Answer (score 1):

While this does not use the functions named, I'd develop a run-length encoding, which is easy given that we know the elements are sorted.

```
rle :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
rle [] = []
rle lst = reverse $ go lst []
  where
    go [] acc = acc
    go (x:xs) [] = go xs [(x, 1)]
    go (x:xs) ((y, c):ys) 
      | x == y = go xs ((y, c+1):ys)
      | otherwise = go xs ((x, 1):(y, c):ys)
```

Now we just need to be able to count the number of tuples that have three or four as their second element.

```
ghci> length $ filter (\(_, c) -> c == 4) $ rle [1,1,1,2,4,5]
0
ghci> length $ filter (\(_, c) -> c == 4) $ rle [1,1,1,1,2,4,5]
1
ghci> length $ filter (\(_, c) -> c == 4) $ rle [1,1,1,1,2,4,4,4,4,5]
2
```